# Scrolling datatable primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, facelets

Datatable columns misaligned with the cell data when set the scroll option scrolling = true.
Any solution to this problem or is primefaces bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the width attribute of each <p:column/>, once you do that, they will align perfectly every time.